# Microsoft Report Builder 2016 Parameter of Start Date Issue

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

I am showing header in my report showing two parameters Start Date and End Date. Both parameters' type is Date/Time. While setting in the Number Format in placeholder settings I tried to print the Date Like 01-MAR-2020 to 31-MAR-2020 using =UCase(Format(Parameters!STARTDATE.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy")) but this is showing FEB as EB, MAR as 3AR and MAY as 5AY. Please share the solution to fix it if any. Thanks

Comment: And for the rest of the Months it worked fine

Comment: that should work fine.. is that the only expression in your placeholder?

Comment: Yes that's the only one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=UCase(Format(Parameters!STARTDATE.Value, "dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

Comment: It displays the Date as 01-02-2021 but I need to display 01-FEB-2020 (Three letters of month name)

Comment: Try converting your parameter to a date and let me know if that makes a difference. 

```=UCase(Format(cdate(Parameters!STARTDATE.Value), "dd-MMM-yyyy")) ```
I

Comment: HamiltonPharmD Same Problem. Parameters!STARTDATE.Value its already date value so bu converting it to Date. Same result found

Comment: Very odd! I used `=UCase(Format(cdate("2021-02-01"), "dd-MMM-yyyy"))` in an attempt to duplicate your issue but was unable to (Output worked just fine). Based on the information you provided in the Microsoft forum, I wonder if you need to uninstall and reinstall Report Builder on your machine?